# Embedding and centring iframe while responsive in landing page builder

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am using Sendinblue and want to embed forms in the page.

However the page looks odd:
https://page.nusaconsult.com/

I've used:

```
<iframe width="350" height="600" src="https://www.chatsurvey.io/embed/i4r" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

With no success. I've tried the solutions from the site like W3schools and even SO but still it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try elaborating the main problem and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly your desired outcome is. But if you use css to give a set height and width to the iframe:

```
iframe {
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

And then center the iframe with the wrapper div:

```
div#c4ad4a16-0e59-47da-86d9-586edca070b4 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

You will get something that looks like this on desktop:

[image]

And on mobile:

[image]

Comment: How would it look like together? The code I mean including the src?

Comment: I just made those CSS changes in dev tools, I didn't touch the iframe element itself. I imagine you'd be able to remove the hard-coded width and height from it though.